# InDesign: Text Won't Go to Top to Text Box

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I am using an already-created document on InDesign (newsletter) to create a new issue. However, I seem unable to get text to go to the top of a text box. When I resize the text box, the text will disappear as it has jumped 10 lines down and the box isn't that large.

My Googling led me to check the text frame options. Under General, the Inset Spacing is all set to zero. Vertical Justification is aligned to the top with no paragraph spacing limit. 
Under Baseline Options, the first baseline is offset to ascent, with a minimum of 0 in. 
Paragraph styles everything is set to zero.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Christie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I would suggest adding a screenshot of your paragraph settings. Also does this happen every time you make a new text box? When you say 10 lines, is it actually just going to the next line and your line-height is very high? By default text starts at the very top left of a text box. Is your space after for paragraph options set really high?

Comment: This is tech support and off topic ----- however... baseline grid.

Comment: Thanks AndrewH, this does happen every time I make a new text box. It is saying that the middle (not exact middle fyi, so I dont think its centering) is the first line, as in i cant backspace up to the top or anything. Space before and after both set to zero!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a near by object has a text wrap (even another text box). Click near by objects and check your Text Wrap window. Turn it off if you don't need it.

Comment: yup, a possibility. In the Text Frame Options there is a checkbox to Ignore Text Wraps.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I checked Ignore Text Wrap and the text automatically jumped to the top of the text box. Thanks so much for the speedy responses everyone, what a great site!!